# Prepend a single line to file with Ruby

Tags: ruby, file-io, prepend

I'd like to add a single line to the top a of file with Ruby like this:

```
# initial file contents
something
else

# file contents after prepending "hello" on its own line
hello
something
else
```

The following code just replaces the contents of the entire file:

```
f = File.new('myfile', 'w')
f.write "test string"
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

This is a pretty common task:

```
original_file = './original_file'
new_file = original_file + '.new'
```

Set up the test:

```
File.open(original_file, 'w') do |fo|
  %w[something else].each { |w| fo.puts w }
end
```

This is the actual code:

```
File.open(new_file, 'w') do |fo|
  fo.puts 'hello'
  File.foreach(original_file) do |li|
    fo.puts li
  end
end
```

Rename the old file to something safe:

```
File.rename(original_file, original_file + '.old')
File.rename(new_file, original_file)
```

Show that it works:

```
puts `cat #{original_file}`
puts '---'
puts `cat #{original_file}.old`
```

Which outputs:

```
hello
something
else
---
something
else
```

You don't want to try to load the file completely into memory. That'll work until you get a file that is bigger than your RAM allocation, and the machine goes to a crawl, or worse, crashes.

Instead, read it line by line. Reading individual lines is still extremely fast, and is scalable. You'll have to have enough room on your drive to store the original and the temporary file.

Answer (score 7):

fwiw this seems to work:

```
#!usr/bin/ruby

f = File.open("myfile", "r+")
lines = f.readlines
f.close

lines = ["something\n"] + lines

output = File.new("myfile", "w")
lines.each { |line| output.write line }
output.close
```

Comment: Be careful slurping the file. It is not a scalable solution to read an entire file into memory.

Comment: I like this for simple tinkering, personally.

Comment: Best solution for the simple case.

Answer (score 6):

I have came up with something like this, it is a little bit more descriptive and less cryptic than other solutions I've seen:

```
def file_prepend(file, str)
  new_contents = ""
  File.open(file, 'r') do |fd|
    contents = fd.read
    new_contents = str << contents
  end
  # Overwrite file but now with prepended string on it
  File.open(file, 'w') do |fd| 
    fd.write(new_contents)
  end
end
```

And you can use it like this:

```
file_prepend("target_file.txt", "hello world!\n")
```

Comment: Great answer! Can reuse it throughout an app. Best solution IMO. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

As some have said, probably don’t use this for larger files, but it is a simple start.

```
rd = IO.read 'myfile'
IO.write 'myfile', "hello\n" + rd
```

Answer (score 3):

No mechanism exists to do what you want to do easily.

Instead, you will need to open the file, delete the file, open a new file by the old name for writing, write your content, and then write the new file from the old file's contents. That's pretty convoluted sounding but is straightforward in code:

```
$ cat prepend.rb 
#!/usr/bin/ruby

File.open("passwd", "r") do |orig|
    File.unlink("passwd")
    File.open("passwd", "w") do |new|
        new.write "test string"
        new.write(orig.read())
    end
end
```

Note that the mechanism I've used doesn't bother checking errors -- you should probably handle errors on each `File.open()` request and the `File.unlink()` request -- and it assumes that the entire contents of the file will fit in memory. A short example:

```
$ rm passwd
$ cp /etc/passwd .
$ ./prepend.rb 
$ head passwd
test stringroot:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
daemon:x:1:1:daemon:/usr/sbin:/bin/sh
bin:x:2:2:bin:/bin:/bin/sh
sys:x:3:3:sys:/dev:/bin/sh
sync:x:4:65534:sync:/bin:/bin/sync
games:x:5:60:games:/usr/games:/bin/sh
man:x:6:12:man:/var/cache/man:/bin/sh
lp:x:7:7:lp:/var/spool/lpd:/bin/sh
mail:x:8:8:mail:/var/mail:/bin/sh
news:x:9:9:news:/var/spool/news:/bin/sh
$
```

If you want to handle files that might not fit entirely in memory, you should code a loop sort of like this (untested --  better consider it pseudo-code):

```
while (data=orig.read(4096)) {
    new.write(data)
}
```

As an alternative, you could write to a temporary file, and if the writing process succeeds, *then* delete the file and rename the temporary file in place. Whichever approach makes the most sense to you.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this:

```
File.copy_stream(myfile,tempfile)
f = File.open(myfile,'w')
f.write("Hello\n#{File.open(tempfile,'r').read}")
f.close
File.delete(tempfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

From the command line, you can do:

```
ruby -i -pe '$_= "prepended text\n"+$_ if $. == 1' myfile
```

or more efficiently

```
ruby -i -pe 'BEGIN { gets; print "prepended text\n" + $_ }; ' myfile
```

Sadly, it turns out, the `-i` (in-place) options isn't truly in-place, though (and nor is `sed`s in-place option for that matter) -- my file will have a different inode after the op.

That made me sad, because effectively, I can't filter through (prepend to) a huge file if I don't have enough diskspace for two copies of it.

It's not really difficult to do it in-place, though (filtering in general, not just for the first line). All you need to do is:

1) make sure, you have separate read and write pointers (or separate File objects for reading and writing)
2) make sure you have buffered the unread parts that you are going to rewrite
3) truncate to file at the end if your filtering operation should end up with a shorter file

I wrote  wrapper class for that at   https://github.org/pjump/i_rewriter .

With it, you can do

```
Rewriter.new("myfile") do |line, index|
  index == 0 ? "prepended text\n" + line : line
end
```

or with the executable:

```
$  i_rewriter 'index == 0 ? "prepended text\n" + line : line' myfile
```

Use carefully (it can corrupt your file if interrupted).

Answer (score 0):

Pure, but works. Minimize file-related operations.

```
`#!/bin/ruby
inv_file = File.open("./1.txt","r+") { |f|
    #Read file string by-string
    until f.eof?
        #Searching for some
        if f.readline[/condition here/]
            #remember position
            offset = f.pos
            #Find it? - stop reading
            break
        end
    end
    #Remember what contains rest of file
    tail = f.readlines
    #Again to offset
    f.pos = offset
    #insert what necessary
    f.puts "INSERTED"
    #reconstruct tail
    f.write tail.join
    }`
```